# Cannot compile code for connection to mySQL server from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-phone-8.1

I want to insert some data from my phone into mySQL database. I have the following code:

```
 MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        conn_string.Server = "";
        conn_string.UserID = "";
        conn_string.Password = "";
        conn_string.Database = "";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {    
            cmd.CommandText = "";
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

I added reference to mySql.data.dll as was said in tutorial which I used but When I try to compile it, I receive these errors. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You sure you add `using Sysdam.Data`?

Comment: I can't add this. It says: "The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' "

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors **as text**. That way, somebody searching for the same errors has a chance of finding your question (and could possibly help you). Leave the image in for reference if you need, but in this case the question should stand on its own without the image.

Comment: I found a solution - I can't use mySQL on Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Comment: First of all: You'd have to add a reference to "System.Data.dll", which you can not do on Windows Phone. Secondly you can not use MySql from your windows phone. One solution would be to create a service on a server your phone interacts with. The service does the database work.